# Polynomial Regression with for loop

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

for Boston dataset perform polynomial regression with degree 5,4,3 and 2 I want to use loop but get error :

Error in `[.data.frame`(data, 0, cols, drop = FALSE) :
undefined columns selected

```
library(caret)


train_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number=10)
#set.seed(5)
cv <-rep(NA,4)
n=c(5,4,3,2)
for (i in n) {
 
 cv[i]=train(nox ~ poly(dis,degree=i ), data = Boston, trncontrol = train_control, method = "lm")

}
```

outside the loop train(nox ~ poly(dis,degree=i ), data = Boston, trncontrol = train_control, method = "lm")
works well

Comment: Where does your `Boston` dataset come from?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/code/prasadperera/the-boston-housing-dataset

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `poly(..., raw = FALSE)` that means you are getting orthogonal contrasts. Hence no need of for-loop, use the maximum degree since the coefficients and standard errors will not change for each coefficient.

Check quick example below using lm and iris dataset:

```
summary(lm(Sepal.Length~poly(Sepal.Width, 2), iris))

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ poly(Sepal.Width, 2), data = iris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.63153 -0.62177 -0.08282  0.50531  2.33336 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            5.84333    0.06692  87.316   <2e-16 ***
poly(Sepal.Width, 2)1 -1.18838    0.81962  -1.450   0.1492    
poly(Sepal.Width, 2)2 -1.41578    0.81962  -1.727   0.0862 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8196 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.03344,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02029 
F-statistic: 2.543 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: 0.08209
> summary(lm(Sepal.Length~poly(Sepal.Width, 3), iris))

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ poly(Sepal.Width, 3), data = iris)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6876 -0.5001 -0.0876  0.5493  2.4600 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            5.84333    0.06588  88.696   <2e-16 ***
poly(Sepal.Width, 3)1 -1.18838    0.80687  -1.473   0.1430    
poly(Sepal.Width, 3)2 -1.41578    0.80687  -1.755   0.0814 .  
poly(Sepal.Width, 3)3  1.92349    0.80687   2.384   0.0184 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8069 on 146 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06965,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.05054 
F-statistic: 3.644 on 3 and 146 DF,  p-value: 0.01425
```

Take a look at the summary table. Everything is the same. Only the poly(Sepal.Width,3)3 was added when a degree of 3 was used. Meaning if we used a degree of 3, we could easily tell what degree 2 will look like. Hence no need of for loop.

Note that you could use different variables in `poly`: eg `poly(cbind(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width), 4)` and still be able to easily recover `poly(Sepal.Width, 2)`.

Comment: can you figure out why loop is not work as  I have get model for 5,4,3,and 2 degrees.

Comment: @nailamunir I just explained why you do not need a loop. Just use a 5degree then select the ones for 2 degree if you need to